# Fair division of a kingdom

Tags: algorithm

Recently, I've attended programming competition. There was a problem from it that I am still mulling over.  Programming language does not matter, but I've wrote it in C++. The task was this:

> As you already know, Flatland is located on the plane. There are n
>   cities in Flatland, i-th of these cities is located at the point *(xi,
>   yi)*. There are *ai* citizens living in i-th city. The king of
>   Flatland has decided to divide the kingdom between his two sons. He
>   wants to build a wall in the form of infinite straight line; each of
>   the parts will be ruled by one of the sons. The wall cannot pass
>   through any city. To avoid envy between brothers, the populations of
>   two parts must be as close as possible; formally, if *a* and *b* are
>   the total number of citizens living in cities of the first and the
>   second part respectively, the value of *|a - b|* must be minimized.
>   Help the king to find the optimal division. Number of cities is less
>   than 1000. And all coordinates are integers. Output of algorithm
>   should be integer number of minimal *|a-b|*

Okay, if I knew the direction of line, it will be really easy task - binary search: [image: Black numbers are population of cities, and red is total population in that part]

**I don't want code**, I want ideas because I don't have any. If I catch idea I can write code!

I don't know optimal direction, but I think it could be found somehow. So could it be found or is this task solved other way?

An example where the horizontal/vertical line is not optimal:

```
1

\
 \
2 \      1
```

Comment: Looks like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis could help.

Comment: well... if you know the direction it is trivial to find the correct division

Comment: The problem doesn't mention anything about the radius of a city. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: my first guess would be that the line crosses the "center of gravity"

Comment: if this is true you would just have to find the right angle

Comment: About how many points are we talking... I think I've found a way, but it doesn't scale extremely well with the number of cities...

Comment: @CommuSoft I changed the picture to avoid further confusion. There are no radius of cities.

Comment: @DoctorMoisha: can you give the bounds on the number of cities. As long as it doesn't run in the `10k+` I think I have a feasible solution.

Comment: For what it's worth, the general version of this problem (called a fair division, or the "cake cutting" problem) is a very active area of research, and solutions are usually not trivial, and usually assume just one dimension, not two. I would guess that the judges have designed this problem in such a way so that it admits a nicer algorithm, but don't know what it would be off hand.

Comment: @SebastianK If you are talking about SVD, it is good variant, but not for a competition with 6 tasks, and time limit of 2 hours.

Comment: is it a "weighted least squares" problem - you know the line will be y =mx + c 
it is then a matter of calculating m and c - I guess there is a problem if the line goes through one of the cities

Comment: @CommuSoft Number of cities less than 1000

Comment: I would add that the left kingdom appears to be solved with a horizontal line would split the kingdom evenly in terms of cities between the brothers. The middle one is most complicated of the three and appears that an angled line would accomplish this there. The right one looks like a vertical line would accomplish this. Nothing seems to stipulate that the  infinite line must be in a certain direction to accomplish this division into 2. It is also interesting that a fair split of land isn't specified as a factor (that could also create "envy" -- "you have more land than I do!")

Comment: @Jimmy: the weighted least square problem is a continuous problem. This is a discrete problem which makes the problem harder.

Comment: @JohnDoucette There is a testing machine. You write algorithm and send code to server, if code does not exceed time and memory limits and does and passes every test - you get one point. And even if they are looking for any algorithm, I'm really looking for any algorithm, because I have nothing)

Comment: @localhost: the red numbers represent the sums of the two halves; not cities itself. These are all the same problem.

Comment: @DoctorMoisha: Is it ok if I first answer this with an idea how to solve this (without any code). I'm currently a bit too busy.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that no more than 2 cities are collinear?

Comment: @CommuSoft It is perfectly nice, because I want idea, and then write code myself.

Comment: @IVlad I think not, because I presented all the task.

Comment: @tobi303: "Center of gravity" definitely does not help here; consider a city with population 1 very very far away.

Comment: Maybe pick the direction such that it is as close to your binary search scenario as possible.  Find some measure of "eccentricity" to measure which direction the cities are the most stretched out in.  Force your line to be perpendicular to that direction and do the binary search.  I can think of corner cases where this would definitely not work though.

Comment: @ IVlad: A re-read has told me my skimming was inadequate; minimization of |a-b| was originally considered as # data points on either side of the line

Comment: Regarding the diagram: Are there always two identical cities in Flatland's top left and bottom right corners? And are the extremes of Flatland always defined by a city in a corner (rather than on a top/bottom/right/left-most edge)?

Comment: @Augusta No, positions of cities are arbitrary. And borders are for binary search. We place first guess line in center of rectangle, containing of cities.

Comment: @DoctorMoisha: do you have any sample data?

Comment: I have two exmples of input and output. Cities are given in form (xi,yi,ai). First is 3 cities: (0 0 1) (10 0 1) (0 10 1). Output is 1. Second one is 4 cities:(0 0 10) (10 0 5) (0 10 4) (10 10 2). Output is 1.

Comment: Closest thing I could find was http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/260/E (contest problem, closed, but with 9 sons instead of 2 and limited directions for the dividing lines).

Comment: Wouldn't this be more appropriate on Programmers?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why so many of the ancient kings got killed. Imagine a realm where there is 1 city with twice the population of all the other cities. And that city sits right in the middle. Any straight line solution will result in the murder of the king ;)

Answer (score 9):

**The Ansatz**

A brute force method would be to check all possible division...

First it should be noted, that the exact orientation of the line does not matter. It can always be shifted by small amounts and there are cases with more than one minimum. What matters it what cities go to which side of the kingdom. Even when simply trying all such possible combinations, it is not trivial to find them. To do so, I propose the following algorithm:

**How to find all possible divisions**

- For each pair of cities x and y, the line connecting them, divides the kingdom in "left" and "right". Then consider all possible combinations of left, right, x and y:

  - `left + x + y`  vs `right` (C)
  - `left + x` vs `right + y` (A)
  - `left + y` vs `right + x` (D)
  - `left` vs `right + x + y` (B)

Actually I am not 100% sure but I think in this way you can find all possible division with a finite number of trials. As the cities have no size (I assumed 0 radius), the line connecting x and y can be shifted slightly to include either city on either side of the kindom.

One counter example where this simple method will definitely fail is when more than 2 cities lie on a straight line

**Example**

This picture illustrates one step of my above algorithm for the example from the OP. x and y are the two cities with 1 inhabitants. Actually with this pair of cities one gets already all possible divisions. (However 3 points is trivial anyhow, as there is no geometrical restriction on what combinations are possible. Interestingly only starting with 4 points their location on the plane really matters.)

[image]

**Colinear points**

Following some discussion and fruitful comments, I came to the conclusion that colinear points are not really a problem. One just has to consider these points when evaluating the 4 possible divisions (for each pair of points). E.g. assume in the above example is another point at (-1,2). Then this point would lie on the left for A and C and on the right for B and D.

Comment: Another one: `(0,0)/2` - `(0,1)/1` and `(1,0)/1`. Weights on the right. The optimal split is a line of `45` degrees. Such that `(0,0)` is placed one one side and the other points on the other side.

Comment: @CommuSoft hm? This example would work for my algorithm

Comment: @tobi303: why do you think it will fail if more cities are on a straight line? it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Well there are three lines: a horizontal one, such that one can only group the origin with one of the two, the vertical (same story) and the one perpendicular on the two non-origins (but that crosses with the origin and again groups one of the points with the origin).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath because then its not so easy anymore to a) decide on wich side the third one goes and because b) my argument with "slightly shifting the line" does not work anymore

Comment: @CommuSoft: if I understand the task correctly, you cannot devise a scenario where there's only one optimal line. moving or rotating the line with a small epsilon should yield the same result.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I've updated the question with an example. The only optimal line is one that goes downward, but you cannot generate this by defining lines perpendicular on the line between the two cities.

Comment: @CommuSoft Sorry I do not get your point, for your example, I would find that the line between `(0,1)` and `(1,0)` with the first point on one side and the others on the other side is a minimum. That is really not a counter example

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I am not talking about anything perpendicular. And CommuSoft is right, there is not only "one" optimal line. You can shift it up and down, as long as it divides the cities in the same way.

Comment: So long as you confine yourself to horizontal and vertical lines the search period for this is quite low--you can use a binary search to find the optimal point for the line.  Unfortunately, there are an infinite number of angles.

Comment: @tobi303: well I have a similar idea but without the split, but with the border so quite the opposite. It is based on support vector machines.

Comment: @LorenPechtel did you want to comment the OP?? Did I make myself so unclear? I am not restricting to horizontal and vertical lines. To the contrary, I claim that I can find the optimal division no matter of its any orientation (if there are no 3 cities on a straight line)

Comment: @tobi303 There are an infinite number of angles, thus you would need an infinite number of tries to brute force every angle.

Comment: @tobi303 I'm a litte bit slow and do not understand your answer. Give me some time.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I think you didnt get my point. I claim that I do not have to take into account any possible angle, because (if I am right, and if there are no more than 2 cities on a straight line) my algorithm takes into account all possible divisions. And that what is asked for and not the angle (the angle does not matter, as anyway it can vary, see e.g. example in the OP)

Comment: @DoctorMoisha no problem ;) I will dry to draw something to make it more clear

Comment: @tobi303: This is a pretty good idea (+1). And I think it can be fixed up to deal with collinear points... Imagine starting with a line that is a "right" answer, and just rotate it until it kisses one point. Then keep rotating about that point until it kisses another point. *That* is the configuration you are exploring, and you can undo it by trying an epsilon-rotation about each endpoint, even in the collinear cases.

Comment: @Nemo: but it fails in the same way as the other idea fails. Please look at the example in the question. The only possible splits are (1) O against Top (horizontal); (2) O against right (vertical); (3) Top against right (upward). Whereas downward is the most optimal split.

Comment: @CommuSoft I still do not get your point. My method will not fail in this case. Maybe the picture I added makes it more clear.

Comment: @tobi303 I've got it, I think! But part about slighlty shifted seems a bit inelegant. What if first slight shift moves line to intersect with other point? I think, there should be some alorithm too.

Comment: @DoctorMoisha A point has zero radius, thus you can always make the shift so small that it effects only that single point while all others cities do not change. However, this argument does not hold if there is another city on the line between x and y, because then any shift (no matter how small) will also change this third point.

Comment: @CommuSoft: I think this method works fine unless there are collinear points. And you can get rid of collinear points by perturbing all locations by teeny-tiny amounts...

Comment: @tobi303: I think I finally understand your answer. I'm not completely convinced this works (don't saying it doesn't).

Comment: @Nemo Actually as an experimentalist I do not bother too much about colinear points. With real numbers as coordinates, this rarely happens :P I am more concerned about the fact that I am not 100% sure if my method really covers all possible division (in more complicated cases, i hope I defended enough against the simple example with 3 points ;)

Comment: @tobi303: He specified that the coordinates are all integers

Comment: This is a good solution.  To deal with collinear points properly, notice that every set of k collinear points x1, ..., xk can be ordered (e.g. from left to right or top to bottom).  Then for any 1 <= i <= k, it's always possible to split x1, ..., xi from xi+1, ..., xk by pinning the line between xi and xi+1 and then epsilon-rotating, and *no other splits of these k points are possible*.

Comment: @Nemo damn I missed that point. Well, then one has to treat such points extra when "applying the slight shifts", ie. the colinear points have to be takin into acount when getting the 4 possible division for each pair.

Comment: To the people complaining about epsilon-rotations being ugly: Instead of doing this, you can find the first point that the line would hit if you continued to rotate it around its fixed "centre" point.  Call this minimum rotation angle a.   Now simply rotate the line by a/2.

Answer (score 4):

For each angle `A`, consider the family of parallel lines which make an angle of `A` with the x-axis, with special case `A=0` corresponding to the family of lines parallel to the X-axis.

Given `A`, you can use a binary search to find the line in the family which divides the kingdom most nearly equally. So we have a function `f` from angles to integers, mapping each angle `A` to the minimum value of `|a-b|` for lines in the family corresponding to `A`.

How many angles do we need to try? The situation changes materially only when `A` is an angle corresponding to a line between two points, an angle which I will call a "jump angle". The function is continuous, and therefore constant, away from jump angles. We have to try jump angles, of which there are about `n choose 2`, approximately 500,000 at most. We also have to try intervals of angles between jump angles, doubling the size, to 1,000,000 at most.

Instead of angles, it's probably more sensible to use slopes. I just like thinking in terms of angles.

The time complexity of this approach is `O(n^2 log n)`, `n^2` for the number of angles, `log n` for the binary search. If we can learn more about the function `f`, it may be possible to use a faster method to minimize `f` than checking every possibility. For example, it seems reasonable that the minimum of `f` can be found at an angle not equal to a jump angle.

<strike>It may also be possible to eliminate the binary search by using the **centroid** of the cities. We calculate the weighted average</strike>

```
(a1(x1,y1) + a2(x2,y2) + ... + an(xn,yn))/(a1+a2+...+an)
```

I think that lines balancing the population will pass through that point. (Hmm.) If that's the case, we only have to think about angles.

Comment: Since the naive solution of trying all `O(n^2)` lines connecting two points is faster than this, I don't really see how it is useful. However, the last remark on optimal dividers passing through the centroid is an interesting idea; that might give us something faster if it is true.

Comment: You're right about speed, but this way of thinking is useful to me as a way of clarifying the question. Speed is secondary to correctness. Re: centroid, it doesn't work exactly (it finds the center of mass which depends on distance not just population size) but there may be another similar idea that works.

Comment: @G.Bach  As I mentioned in a comment on the original question, the centroid hypothesis is obviously false. Consider a single city placed very very far from all of the others. You can use it to "drag" the centroid as far from the bulk of the population as you want. Then imagine moving that point in an enormous circle around the remaining cities; by doing so, you can force the line to be any angle you want, which is clearly nonsense.

Comment: Not a bad answer (except for the bogus "centroid" hypothesis), so +1. I think you can improve on this by doing: For each point, try each angle to each other point. Perturb angle and shift line +- epsilon to cover all cases. By updating totals as you rotate and perturb, I think this gives you O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

## Case where *n* is less than `3`

The base case is where there are two cities: in which case you simple take the perpendicular line on the line that connects the two cities.

## Case with three or more cities

You can **discretize the tangent** by taking every pair of two cities, and see the line that connects them as the direction of the infinite line.

**Why this works**

If you split the number of cities in two parts, there is at least one half with two or more cities. For that part, there are two points that are the closest to the border. Whether the border passes "very closely" to that line or has the same line does not matter; because a "slightly different tangent" will not swap any city (otherwise these cities were not the closest). Since we try "every border", we will eventually generate a border with the given tangent.

**Example:**

Say you have the following scenario:

```
1
\
2\ 1
```

With the numbers showing the values. In this case the two closest points at the border are the one at the top and the right. So we construct a line that points 45 degrees downwards. Now we use binary search to find the most optimal split: we rotate all points, order them by ascending rotated x-value, then perform binary search on the weights. The optimal one is to split it between the origin and the two other points.

Now with four points:

```
1    2

2    1
```

Here we will investigate the following lines:

```
\ 1\|/2 /
 \ /|\ /
----+----
 / \|/ \
/ 2/|\1 \
```

And this will return either the horizontal or the vertical line.

There is a single possibility - as pointed out by @Nemo that all these points are lying on the same line. In such case there is no tangent that makes sense. In that case, one can use the perpendicular tangent as well.

### Pseudocode:

```
for v in V
    for w in V\{v}
        calculate tangent
        for tangent and perpendicular tangent
            rotate all points such that the tangent is rotated to the y-axis
            look for a rotated line in the y-direction that splits the cities optimal
return the best split found
```

Furthermore as nearly all geometrical approaches, this method can suffer from the fact that multiple dots are located on the same line in which case by adding a simple rotation one can either include/exclude one of the points. This is indeed a dirty hack to the problem.

This Haskell program calculates the "optimal direction" (if the above solution is correct) for a given list of points:

```
import Data.List

type Point = (Int,Int)
type WPoint = (Point,Int)
type Direction = Point

dirmul :: Direction -> WPoint -> Int
dirmul (dx,dy) ((xa,ya),_) = xa*dx+ya*dy

dirCompare :: Direction -> WPoint -> WPoint -> Ordering
dirCompare d pa pb = compare (dirmul d pa) (dirmul d pb)

optimalSplit :: [WPoint] -> Direction
optimalSplit pts = (-dy,dx)
    where wsum = sum $ map snd pts
          (dx,dy) = argmin (bestSplit pts wsum) $ concat [splits pa pb | pa <- pts, pb <- pts, pa /= pb]

splits :: WPoint -> WPoint -> [Direction]
splits ((xa,ya),_) ((xb,yb),_) = [(xb-xa,yb-ya),(ya-yb,xb-xa)]

bestSplit :: [WPoint] -> Int -> Direction -> Int
bestSplit pts wsum d = bestSplitScan cmp ordl 0 wsum
    where cmp = dirCompare d
          ordl = sortBy cmp pts

bestSplitScan :: ((a,Int) -> (a,Int) -> Ordering) -> [(a,Int)] -> Int -> Int -> Int
bestSplitScan _ [] l r = abs $ l-r
bestSplitScan cmp ((x1,w1):xs) l r = min (abs $ l-r) (bestSplitScan cmp (dropWhile eqf xs) (l+d) (r-d))
    where eqf = (==) EQ . cmp (x1,w1)
          d = w1+(sum $ map snd $ takeWhile eqf xs)

argmin :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
argmin _ [x] = x
argmin f (x:xs) | (f x) <= f ax = x
                | otherwise = ax
    where ax = argmin f xs
```

For instance:

```
*Main> optimalSplit [((0,0),2),((0,1),1),((1,0),1)]
(-1,1)
*Main> optimalSplit [((0,0),2),((0,1),1),((1,0),1),((1,1),2)]
(-1,0)
```

So the direction is a line in which if the line moves one element to the left, it moves one element to the top as well. This is the first example. For the second case, it picks a line that moves in the x-direction so it splits horizontally. This algorithm allows only integral points and does not take into account slightly tweaking the line in case the points are placed on the same line: these are *all in* or *all out* for a line parallel.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you do after "taking every pair of two cities, and see the line that connects them as the direction of the infinite line." - this gets you the direction, then what? How do you place the line? You'll have to try moving it and maybe even rotating it, how do you do that?

Comment: I think, I caught your idea. I need to think about it)

Comment: This does not work. Consider if all cities are on the x-axis. You never even bothered to split them at all; every line you consider is the x-axis itself.

Comment: and btw 3 points is still trivial, only starting with 4 points it gets tricky

Comment: @tobi303: well the algorithm does take that into account. That's why it says three or more.

Comment: if it took it into account it should say "four or more"....

Comment: @tobi303: well the point is that the algorithm is a bit different if there are only two points. That's why it is the base case. Four is covered into three or more.

Answer (score 2):

[**Edit:** Bold-faced text is relevant to concerns expressed previously in comments.]

[**Edit 2:** As I should have pointed out earlier, this answer is a supplement to the earlier answer by tobi303, which gives a similar algorithm. The main purpose was to show that the basic idea of that algorithm is sound and sufficiently general.
Despite minor differences in the details of the algorithms proposed in the two answers, I think a careful reading of the "why it works" section, *applied to either algorithm,* will show that the algorithm is in fact complete.]

If all the cities are in one straight line
(including the case where there
are only one or two cities), then the solution is simple.
**I assume you can detect and solve this case, so the rest of the
answer will deal with all other cases.**

If there are more than two cities and they are not all collinear,
the "brute force" solution is:

```
for each city X, 
  for each city Y where Y is not X
    construct a directed line that passes through X and then Y.
    Divide the cities in two subsets: 
    S1 = all the cities to the left of this line
    S2 = all the other cities (including cities exactly on the line)
    Evaluate the "unfairness" of this division.
```

Among all subdivisions of cities found in this way,
choose the one with the least unfairness. Return the difference. Done.

**Note that the line found in this way is not the line that divides the cities "fairly"; it is merely parallel to some such line.**
If we had to find the actual dividing line we would have to do a little more work to figure out
exactly where to put that parallel line. But the requested return value
is merely |a-b|.

Why this works:

Suppose that the line L1 divides the cities in the fairest way possible.
There is not a *unique* line that does this;
there will be (mathematically speaking) an infinite number of lines
that achieve the same "best" division, but such lines exist, and
all we need to suppose is that L1 is one of those lines.

Let the city A be the closest to L1 on one side of the line
and the city B be closest to L1 on the other side.
(If A and B are not uniquely identified, that is if there are two or more
cities on one side of L1 that are tied for "closest to L1",
we can set L2 = L1 and skip forward to the procedure for L2, below.)

Consider rotations of L1 in each direction, using the point where L1 crosses
the line AB as a pivot point. In at least one direction of rotation,
a rotated image of L1 will "hit" one of the other cities, 
call it C, without touching either A or B.
(This follows from the fact that the cities are not all along one line.)
At that point, C is closer to the image of L1 than A or B (whichever
of those cities is on the same side of the original L1 as C was).
The Mean Value Theorem of calculus tells us that at some point during
the rotation, C was exactly as close to the rotated image of L1
as the city A or B, whichever is on the same side of that line.

What this shows is that there is always a line L2 that divides the cities
as fairly as possible, such that there are two cities, D and E,
on the same side of L2 and tied for "closest city to L2" among all
cities on that side of L2.

Now consider two directed lines through D and E: L3, which passes through
D and then E, and L4, which passes through E and then D.
The cities that are on the other side of L2 than D and E consist either of
all the cities to the left of L3, or all the cities to the left of L4.
**(Note that this works even if L3 and L4 happen
to pass through more than two cities.)**

The procedure described before is simply a way to find all possible
lines **that could be line L3 or line L4** in any execution of this
procedure starting from a line L1 that solves the problem.
**(Note that while there are always infinite possible choices of L1,
every such L1 results in lines L3 and L4 selected from the finite set of
lines that pass through two or more cities.)**
So the procedure will find the division of cities described by L1,
which is the solution to the problem.

Comment: The line is not supposed to cross a city as you propose. And once you fix this, I wonder how this is different from my solution.

Comment: BTW, I agree, the actual algorithm is basically what you wrote (though with fewer cases of putting A and B on different sides of the line). The value I hoped to add was that it proves that the algorithm always works (and works even with some minor simplifications).

Comment: Dont you miss lines that puts x on the left and y on the right (for some particular x and y) in your pseudo code?

Comment: I think one has to make this 4 cases, otherwise you will miss some divisions. Imagine a number of cities along the x axis and some along the y axis. Then the optimal line cannot be constructed from a connection line between two cities by putting both cities on the same side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78848/discussion-between-david-k-and-tobi303).